Subsets of real numbers equal to some shifts
Let $A$ be a subset of real numbers. It is interesting to know that
$$
\{1,2\}+A=A\Leftrightarrow 1+A=2+A=A \Leftrightarrow 1+A=A
$$
But, it seems that for $\{2,3\}$ we don't have such two-sided property (of course,
$2+A=3+A=A \Rightarrow \{2,3\}+A=A$).
Any counterexample for:
(a) $\{2,3\}+A=A\Rightarrow2+A=A$ and $3+A=A$ ?
(b) $\{2,3\}+A=A\Rightarrow2+A=A$ or $3+A=A$ ?
Thanks in advance

What does ${1,2} + A$ mean? How do you define addition of sets?

$B+A:={ b+a : b\in B , a\in A}$

Therefore ${1,2}+A=(1+A)\cup (2+A)$.

If $\{2, 3\} + A = A$, then for all $a \in A$ we have $$(a + 2 \in A) \land (a + 3 \in A)$$ and $$(a - 2 \in A) \lor (a - 3 \in A)$$
By cases, we have that:

if $a - 2 \in A$, then $a - 2 + 3 = a + 1 \in A$. By cases again,

if $a - 2 - 2 \in A$, then $a - 2 - 2 + 3 = a - 1 \in A$;
if $a - 2 - 3 \in A$, then $a - 2 - 3 + 2 + 2 = a - 1 \in A$;


if $a - 3 \in A$, then $a - 3 + 2 = a - 1 \in A$ and $a - 3 + 2 + 2 = a + 1 \in A$.

Thus for all $a \in A$ we have $a + 1 \in A$ and $a - 1 \in A$, hence $1 + A = A$ (so in particular $2 + A = A$ and $3 + A = A$).
I would be curious to know if this generalises.

Thanks for your answer. But about the generalizes, as you are curious: Does $B+A=A$ imply $\langle B\rangle+A=A$, where $\langle B\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by $B$?             ($B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$)

I don't know. Say $B = {1, x}$, where $x \in (0, 1)$ is irrational, and $A$ is the additive submonoid of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by ${-1, 1, x}$. Then $B + A = A$, but is $-x$ necessarily in $A$? It seems not.

What about the case $B\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$?
